# Discrete Math Anne likes Dave but Dave likes someone else

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Anne likes Dave, but Dave likes someone else.
>
> $$\big(L(\text{Anne},\text{Dave})\neg L(\text{Dave},\text{Anne})\big)\land\exists y\,L(\text{Dave},y)$$

This is what I have; I am unsure if it is correct. Any help/resources is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have isn’t syntactically correct: it’s ungrammatical in terms of the logical notation. You need a conjunction ($\land$) before the negation:

$$\big(L(\text{Anne},\text{Dave})\land\neg L(\text{Dave},\text{Anne})\big)\land\exists y\,L(\text{Dave},y)$$

Now you don’t need the outer parentheses: you can write simply

$$L(\text{Anne},\text{Dave})\land\neg L(\text{Dave},\text{Anne})\land\exists y\,L(\text{Dave},y)\;.$$

In words,

> Anne likes Dave, and Dave does not like Anne, and there is someone whom Dave likes.

This is a correct solution if the *but* in the original sentence is understood to imply that Dave does not like Anne, and that probably is the intent.

Comment: Wow thank you I had the conjunction in there while working it out for awhile but it seemed too clunky to have two of them in the problem. I really appreciate this I am new to but seeing examples like this helps me out a ton thanks again!

Comment: @whatamii: You’re welcome!